# Быстрая обработка Excel документа

Tags: 1с, excel

Добрый день, товарищи!

На Delphi можно загнать всю страницу экселя во внутреннюю OLE переменную, и работать с ней. Что на порядок быстрее, чем чтение/запись ячеек непосредственно из документа.

```
Data:= Sheet.UsedRange.Value; 
...
str:= Data[Row,Col];
```

Можно что-то такое сделать в 1С 8.2 ? Просто идет работа с большим отчетом из которого формируется не менее большой график. Очень много циклов, очень много итераций. Хотелось бы выиграть в скорости хотя бы за счет работы с листом, как с внутренней переменной.

Comment: Ну так и работайте с OLE:  

    Эксель= СоздатьОбъект("Excel.Application");
http://www.mista.ru/articles1c/ole.htm

Comment: @ReinRaus это 7ка. но смысл тот же, да.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно, все также. Только массивы доступны в виде функций. Т.е. Cells[i,j] => Cells(i,j).

```
ФайлыПрайсЛистов = НайтиФайлы(КаталогПрайсЛиста.ПолноеИмя,"*.xls");
Для каждого ФайлПрайсЛист из ФайлыПрайсЛистов Цикл
  Если ФайлПрайсЛист.ЭтоКаталог() Тогда
    Продолжить;
  КонецЕсли;
  Excel = Новый COMОбъект("Excel.Application");
  Excel.Workbooks.Open(ФайлПрайсЛист.ПолноеИмя);
  Sheet = Excel.ActiveWorkbook.WorkSheets(1);
  Сообщить(Sheet.Cells(1,1).Value);
  Excel.Quit();
КонецЦикла;
```

Answer (score 0):

обращение к конкретной ячейке очень медленно, особенно если в экселе 50 колонок и более 10 тыс строк.

Тут я использую два подхода 
1. Чтение через адо в таблицу значений и с ней работаю
2. Читай эксельный файл через табличный документ (открыть) и потом пожалуйста обрабатывай как тебе нравится